# Set print preview paper size according to content size

Tags: css

I have a content in a div to print ,while i see it in goole chrome print preview option it is showing the content in a A4 size paper,but the paper size is too large as compared to my content

is there any way to change the print preview paper size(in chrome) according to content size using css?

Answer (score 0):

Use media @print {

```
#div {
font-size : XXpx; 
}
}
```

increase ur font-size on it .